# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mpi

When I run a program in parallel with MPI, in Ubuntu 20.04, I get the statement:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
```

What is this? Is it impairing something on the program execution? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Changed the driver from NVIDIA do X.ORG and this disappeared...